# Error when reading tsv file to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a TSV file to Pandas Dataframe and I am getting an error

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

Given below is the code I am using.

```
list_ = []
    for file_ in allFiles:
         try:
             df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=None, sep='\t')
             list_.append(df)
             temp = pd.concat(list_)
         except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
             continue
```

Update:

```
1   "ABC"   ""  "XYZ"   "686"   "12345" 
2   "ABC"   ""  "KLM"   "391"   "23456" 
3   "ABC"   ""  "PQR"   "601"   "45678" 
4   "ABC"   ""  "HELLO" "688"   "235754"    
5   "ABC"   ""  "MIKE"  "619"   "355355"    
6   "KINROC"    ""  "NAME"  "1275"  "45433" 
7   "PEPCOL"    ""  "SAMPLE"    "457"   "5553435"
```

Comment: @jezrael, I had also checked that option earlier but it failed.

Comment: Can youexolain more `failed` ?

Comment: @jezrael, tried including error_bad_lines=False and warn_bad_lines=True but got the same error message

Comment: Then no idea, reopened.

Comment: You mention an upload, but I only see code *reading* a CSV file into memory. Could you be clear what it is.

Comment: Please show the first 10 lines of the offending TSV file. The error message seems pretty clear though.

Comment: @9769953, I am trying to read the tsv file and then concat. I had edited my question. Also updated my initial message with a sample of the tsv file I am trying to read